# Keep getting Error: The method getImg() is undefined for the type javax.swing.ImageIcon

Tags: java, swing, imageicon

My friend code this brick breaker game rip off, but he keep getting this error
"Error: The method getImg() is undefined for the type javax.swing.ImageIcon" and I don't know how to fix it. Can someone help?
here the code:

```
public class Ball extends Sprite implements iFace{  
private int xDir;
  private int yDir;

public Ball(){

xDir = 1;
yDir = -1;

String path = "MAJOR_JAVA_ASSESSMENT/ball.png";
ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(path));
img = i.getImg();


iWidth = img.getWidth(null);
iHeight = img.getHeight(null);

reset(); }

  public void move()
  {
    x += xDir;
    y += yDir;

if(x == 0)
{
  setXDir(1);
}

if(x == width - iWidth)
{
  setXDir(-1);
}

if (y == 0)
{
  setYDir(1);
}  }

  private void reset()
  {
    x = initBallX;
    y = initBallY;
  }

  public void setXDir(int x)
  {
    xDir = x;
  }

  public void setYDir(int y)
  {
    yDir = y;
  }

  public int getYDir()
  {
    return yDir;
  }
}
```

here another code for you:

```
  import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Board extends JPanel implements iFace
{

 private Timer timer;
  private String message = "You lose";
  private Ball ball;
  private Paddle paddle;
  private Brick bricks[];
  private boolean inGame = true;

  public Board()
  {
    initBoard();
  }



 private void initBoard()
  {
    addKeyListener(new timeAdapter());
    setFocusable(true);

    bricks = new Brick[numOfBricks];
    setDoubleBuffered(true);
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ScheduleTask(), delay, period);
  }

  @Override
  public void addNotify()
  {
    super.addNotify();
    gameInit();
  }

  private void gameInit()
  {
    ball = new Ball();
    paddle = new Paddle();

int k = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
  {
    bricks[k] = new Brick(j * 40 + 30, i * 10 + 50);
    k++;
  }
}
  }

 @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D) g;

graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

if (inGame)
{
  drawObj(graphics2D);
}

else
{
  gameDone(graphics2D);
}

Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
  }




 private void drawObj(Graphics graphics2D)
  {
    graphics2D.drawImage(ball.getImg(), ball.getX(), ball.getY(), ball.getWidth(), ball.getHeight(), this);
    graphics2D.drawImage(paddle.getImg(), paddle.getX(), paddle.getY(), paddle.getWidth(), paddle.getHeight(), this);

for (int i = 0; i < numOfBricks; i++)
{
  if(!bricks[i].isDead())
  {
    graphics2D.drawImage(bricks[i].getImg(), bricks[i].getX(), bricks[i].getY(), bricks[i].getWidth(), bricks[i].getHeight(), this);
  }
}
  }



  private void gameDone(Graphics2D graphics2D)
  {
    Font f = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 20);
    FontMetrics fm = this.getFontMetrics(f);

    graphics2D.setColor(Color.RED);
    graphics2D.setFont(f);
    graphics2D.drawString(message, (iFace.width - fm.stringWidth(message)) / 2, iFace.width / 2);

  }



  private class timeAdapter extends KeyAdapter
  {
    @Override    
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent p)
    {
      keyReleased(p);
    }

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent p)
{
  keyPressed(p);
}
  }



  private class ScheduleTask extends TimerTask
  {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
      ball.move();
      paddle.move();
      checkCollision();
      repaint();
    }
  }

  private void stopGame()
  {
    inGame = false;
    timer.cancel();
  }



  private void checkCollision()
  {
    if(ball.getRectangle().getMaxY() > iFace.bottom)
    {
      stopGame();
    }

for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < numOfBricks; i++)
{
  if(bricks[i].isDead())
  {
    j++;
  }

  if(j == numOfBricks)
  {
    message = "GG YOU WIN";
    stopGame();
  }
}

if ((ball.getRectangle()).intersects(paddle.getRectangle()))
{
  int paddlePos = (int) paddle.getRectangle().getMinX();
  int ballPos = (int) ball.getRectangle().getMinX();

  int first = paddlePos + 8;
  int second = paddlePos + 16;
  int third = paddlePos + 24;
  int fourth = paddlePos + 32;

  if (ballPos < first)
  {
    ball.setXDir(-1);
    ball.setYDir(-1);
  }

  if (ballPos >= first && ballPos < second)
  {
    ball.setXDir(-1);
    ball.setYDir(-1 + ball.getYDir());
  }

  if (ballPos >= second && ballPos < third)
  {
    ball.setXDir(0);
    ball.setYDir(-1);
  }

  if (ballPos >= third && ballPos < fourth)
  {
    ball.setXDir(1);
    ball.setYDir(-1);
  }
}

for (int i = 0; i < numOfBricks; i++)
{
  if ((ball.getRectangle()).intersects(bricks[i].getRectangle()))
  {
    int ballLeft = (int) ball.getRectangle().getMinX();
    int ballHeight = (int) ball.getRectangle().getHeight();
    int ballWidth = (int) ball.getRectangle().getWidth();
    int ballTop = (int) ball.getRectangle().getMinY();

    Point pR = new Point(ballLeft + ballWidth + 1, ballTop);
    Point pL = new Point(ballLeft - 1, ballTop);
    Point pT = new Point(ballLeft, ballTop - 1);
    Point pB = new Point(ballLeft, ballTop + ballHeight + 1);

    if (!bricks[i].isDead())
    {
      if (bricks[i].getRectangle().contains(pR))
      {
        ball.setXDir(-1);
      }
      else if
        (bricks[i].getRectangle().contains(pL))
      {
        ball.setXDir(1);
      }

      if (bricks[i].getRectangle().contains(pT))
      {
        ball.setYDir(1);
      }
      else if (bricks[i].getRectangle().contains(pB))
      {
        ball.setYDir(-1);
      }

      bricks[i].setDeath(true);
    }
  }
}
  }
}
```

i only give you the ball code as the two codes that have problems are basically have the same problem, so if someone can fix this one then, then we can the rest. 
Also give you board as it the biggest and most important code, so this code may be the problem?
Thank you for reading this, and I hope you can help my friend.

Comment: Isn't it `getImage`?

Comment: yeah it should my bad. thank you

Answer (score 1):

`getImg` does not exist in the `ImageIcon` API, I think you'll find that it's [`ImageIcon#getImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#getImage--) instead

Having said that, I'd recommend using the `ImageIO` API instead